# How to pick and choose columns from dataframes and put them into new ones?

Tags: python, pandas

I sincerely regret going to the pub when i was supposed to be reading up on how to push and shove dataframe data around:

Given two similar shaped dataframes, how do I combine them?

```
> print aae.head(), aar.head()

           symbol      open      high       low     close  volume
date                                                             
1994-02-21    AAE  22.83890  22.83890  20.47626  20.47626    4368
1994-02-22    AAE  20.47626  20.47626  19.68871  19.68871    2120
1994-02-23    AAE  20.47626  22.05135  20.47626  22.05135    7961
1994-02-24    AAE  22.05135  23.62645  22.05135  22.83890    2768
1994-02-25    AAE  22.83890  22.83890  21.26381  21.26381    1778
         symbol      open      high       low     close  volume
date                                                             
1992-01-02  AAR  0.11657  0.11657  0.11657  0.11657   61767
1992-01-03  AAR  0.11657  0.11657  0.11657  0.11657   10294
1992-01-07  AAR  0.12628  0.12628  0.12628  0.12628  102944
1992-01-09  AAR  0.12628  0.12628  0.12628  0.12628  102944
1992-01-10  AAR  0.12628  0.13600  0.12628  0.13600   18530
```

Such that it discards dates which don't appear in both series, and retains only the 'close' columns? something like

```
                 AAE      AAR
date
1994-02-21  20.47626  0.34000
1994-02-22  19.68871  0.34100
```

Comment: Do you want to show the 'open' column or the 'close' column? Seems the  AAE you provide are sames the 'open' column but not the 'close' one.

Comment: symbols... see the edit, sorry I'd stripped that column already since I went on to collect all the tables into a dict keyed by symbol.

Comment: doh. my bad. second edit.

Comment: I've seen a few solutions which map/do list comprehension to 'manually' put the dataframe together. Is that the only way? I was hoping pandas had some basic function to magically do this kind of thing... apply? join?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/merging.html) to achieve your goal. For example:

```
pd.merge(aae.reset_index()[['date', 'close']], aar.reset_index()[['date', 'close']], on=['date'])


 Out[129]:
                   date  close.x  close.y
 0  1992-01-24 00:00:00  1.56073  0.12628
 1  1992-01-31 00:00:00  1.56073  0.12628
 2  1992-02-03 00:00:00  1.56073  0.12628
 3  1992-02-04 00:00:00  1.56073  0.13600
 4  1992-02-12 00:00:00  1.56073  0.13600
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to get the same result to waitingkuo, but broken down into steps:

```
In[127]:
    aae = data['AAT'].close 
    aar = data['AAR'].close 
    df = pd.DataFrame({'AAE': aae, 'AAR': aar}) 
    df = df.dropna() 

    print aae.head() 
    print aar.head() 
    df.head()

Out[127]:
    date
    1992-01-20    1.56073
    1992-01-22    1.56073
    1992-01-24    1.56073
    1992-01-31    1.56073
    1992-02-03    1.56073
    Name: close
    date
    1992-01-02    0.11657
    1992-01-03    0.11657
    1992-01-07    0.12628
    1992-01-09    0.12628
    1992-01-10    0.13600
    Name: close

                    AAE      AAR
    1992-01-24  1.56073  0.12628
    1992-01-31  1.56073  0.12628
    1992-02-03  1.56073  0.12628
    1992-02-04  1.56073  0.13600
    1992-02-12  1.56073  0.13600
```

Comment: Nice, another way to achieve your goal.